# codeigniter controller calling only index function my content page is dynamic taking data from the database

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

This is the controller ERP

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class ERP extends CI_Controller {

public function index(){
$this->load->model("model_get");
$this->load->view("ERP/header");
$data["results"]=$this->model_get->getData(1);
$this->load->view("ERP/menu");
$this->load->view("ERP/new",$data);
$this->load->view("ERP/footer");
  }

public function about(){
echo "HEOO";
$this->load->model("model_get");
$this->load->view("ERP/header");
$data["results"]=$this->model_get->getData(2);
$this->load->view("ERP/menu");
$this->load->view("ERP/ABOUT",$data);
$this->load->view("ERP/footer");
  }


public function sign_in(){
$this->load->view("ERP/header");
$this->load->view("ERP/menu");
$this->load->view("ERP/log_in");
$this->load->view("ERP/footer");
  }
```

This is the html file  with links

```
<li class="active" ><a href="http://localhost/PROJECT1/ERP/index">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="http://localhost/PROJECT1/ERP/about">About</a></li>
 <li><a href="http://localhost/PROJECT1/ERP/sign_in">Sign-In</a></li>
```

when I click on home it calls index that works fine but when I click on about or sign-up it still calls the same index function, on my browser uri it shows 
`http://localhost/PROJECT1/ERP/about` but it actually calls index function

Answer (score 0):

Try This,It works For me

```
<li class="active" ><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>ERP/index">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>ERP/about">About</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>ERP/sign_in">Sign-In</a></li>
```

Comment: Thxs Faran ali for the reply ...i tried that as well n it din't work 
this is the base url 
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/PROJECT1';
this is the html page links 
     <li class="active" ><a href="<?php echo base_url()?>ERP/index">Home</a></li>
                <li  ><a href="<?php echo base_url()?>ERP/about">About</a></li>

this is not working

Comment: Did you remove index.php ?

Answer (score 0):

> Use - site_url().

```
site_url('controllerName/methodName');

<a href="<?php echo site_url('ERP/about'); ?>"> About </a>
```